# distinction between homeomorphic topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to distinguish between topological spaces, given the following image:

> [image: A set of topological spaces]

I think that space $A$ is homeomorphic to space $B$, the function just need to "compact" the semi-plane to a circle, and map the frontier points of the axis to the semi-circumference of the circle. On the other hand i see that between spaces $A$ and $C$ there is not the same number of frontier points, that discrepancy will make impossible to construct a bijective between them. But i am not sure about this arguments, any observation will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It turns out that there *is* the same *number* of frontier points for all three, in the sense of cardinality. However, you're right that only $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic.

Comment: ouch, so it doesn't matter if one set has a "frontier" and the other has "two"?

Comment: Well, the definition of "frontier points" I'm used to is as follows: Given a set $X$ with topology $\mathcal T$ and a subset $E$ of $X,$ a *frontier point* of $X$ is an element $x\in X$ such that, for all $U\in\mathcal T,$ if $x\in U,$ then both $U\cap E$ and $U\cap(X\setminus E)$ are non-empty. Put another way, the frontier points of $E$ are the elements of the closure of $E$ which are not elements of the interior of $E.$

Comment: From that perspective, considering each set as a subset of $\Bbb R^2,$ there are uncountably-infinitely-many frontier points of each set in question. That's what my comment was intended to mean. I believe that Lee Mosher's answer has captured what you seem to have intended by "frontier points."

Comment: Thanks Cameron :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof that $A$ and $C$ are not homeomorphic requires some knowledge.

As Lee Mosher pointed out, you can do it by looking at the boundary components of the manifolds $A, C$.

Another approach is to consider the one-point compactifications $A^+$ of $A$ and $C^+$ of $C$. If $A,C$ would be homeomorphic, then so would be $A^+ , C^+$. But $A^+$ is homeomorphic to a closed disk which is contractible and $C^+$ retracts to a copy of the circle $S^1$ which is not contractible. This is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding $A$ and $B$, you're on the right track, but still there is some hard work to do regarding writing down a formula for the homemorphism.

Regarding $A$ and $C$, your wording "...there is not the same number of frontier points..." is inappropriate, as said the remark of @CameronBuie. But there is a way to alter the wording to make a correct statement, namely:

> ... there is not the same number **of connected components of boundary points** ...

Since I do not know whether you have the background to understand how to make this rigorous, I'll simply list a few concepts that you need to learn for that purpose:

- [Manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold) with an emphasis on [manifolds with boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Manifold_with_boundary), and specialized to manifolds of dimension 2 also known as surfaces. It's important to be aware that in the context of a manifold-with-boundary, the "boundary" is quite different from the "frontier" which you mentioned in your post.
- [Connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space) and [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Connected_components) of topological spaces.

Comment: Thanks Mosher, i'll take a look at that, it seems that i am even more lost that i thought.

Comment: Thanks Mosher, i'll take a look at that, it seems that i am even more lost that i thought. But just to be sure, the construct a homeomorphism between set A and set B it has to map bijectively open sets to open set, and limit points to limit points?. And thanks again for the info.

Comment: Regarding the homeomorphism $A \mapsto B$, that's correct.

Comment: Is there an argument to be made about the cardinality of the topology of set A beign different from the cardinality of set C?, because if they were homeomorphic the bijective relation should map one to one open sets from one to another, but it is not the case, so, is there a different number of open sets in A and C?

Comment: For these examples, cardinality of the topology is not useful: for each of $A,B,C$, the cardinality of the topology is equal to the cardinality of the real numbers.